#  Saving a notebook without output lines

Tags: notebooks, options

Is it possible to change the way Mathematica saves so that `Out[]` lines are never included?

I have a `.nb` file that processes a lot of data, and displays most of it as standard output. These graphs, tables, and intensity plots almost double the size of the file. I'd like to easily save these files in a smaller form and also prevent accidentally sending confidential results to users outside my company or not under an NDA.

That is, of course, without using `Cell -> Delete All Output` before each save. I can't be expected to remember to do that all the time! :-P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `Options Inspector` you can change the `EvaluationOptions` for `Selected Notebook` or for `Global Preferences` by adding

```
  {"WindowClose" :>  FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["DeleteGeneratedCells"]]}
```

to the `NotebookEventActions` line.

**Screenshots for changing the notebook evaluation options in Options Inspector**:

A notebook with Input and Output cells and the Evaluation Options page in Option Inspector

[image: before]

After editing the NotebookEventActions line in Options Inspector or evaluating

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookEventActions -> {"WindowClose" :> 
 FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["DeleteGeneratedCells"]]}];
```

inside the notebook:

[image: after edit]

After clicking `X` on the on the notebooks window frame:

[image: after window close]

After clicking `Yes` on the dialog window:

[image: after yes]

**Alternative**: you can add

```
 SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookEventActions -> {"WindowClose" :> 
 FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["DeleteGeneratedCells"]]}];
```

to a notebook's initialization cell.

Comment: +1 This is probably a better solution than mine. It can be added at a per-notebook level while mine has to be global. Also, the final `SetOptions` approach is very quick to do.

Answer (score 11):

After making a backup of the `MenuSetup.tr` file, you can insert the following line somewhere in the `Menu["&File"...]` section:

```
MenuItem["Delete output and Save", FrontEndExecute[{
    FrontEndToken["DeleteGeneratedCells"], FrontEndToken["Save"]}], 
  MenuKey["X", Modifiers->{"Control", "Shift"}]],
```

I placed it beneath the `MenuItem["&Save"...]` line. You can also change the key combination to something more memorable.

---

To see a list of all frontend tokens go to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4209612/421225

And the following code should give the location of `MenuSetup.tr` on all three supported platforms

```
With[{os = Switch[$OperatingSystem,
    "Unix", "X",
    "MacOSX", "OSX",
    "Windows", "Windows"]}, 
 FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", 
   "TextResources", os, "MenuSetup.tr"}]]
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yeah been busy, but today I had time to procrastinate. Nice moderator diamond, btw!