# Quit Kernel Shortcut

Tags: keyboard

How could I set a Keyboard shortcut for the Quit Kernel -> Local command? I find really disappointing to open the Evaluation menu any time!

Comment: Have a look at the answer to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17357/do-you-really-want-to-quit-the-kernel-yes) Note that just running `Quit[]` quits the kernel too

Comment: You do not need the "[]" after `Quit`. It will save you 2 keystrokes in these times of crisis.