# Prevent Dynamic from behaving dynamically until notebook evaluated

Tags: dynamic

If a notebook containing

```
a = {1, 2};
Dynamic[a[[2]]]
(* 2 *)
```

is executed, closed, and then opened in a new session, it yields

[image]

along with the expected error message,

```
Part::partd: Part specification a[[2]] is longer than depth of object. >>
```

Instead, I would like `Dynamic` not to change the answer from the previous session until the notebook is first executed again.  Thereafter, in the new session it should behave as it normally would.  How can this be accomplished programmatically?  An answer that involves executing `a = {1, 2}` is not useful, because it does not generalize to my actual problem, in which `Dynamic` yields lengthy invalid results, unless the entire preceding portion of the notebook has executed.

**Addendum**

My thanks to  Mike Honeychurch for reminding me to include several variants I had tried that also do not meet my goal.

```
DynamicModule[{}, Dynamic[a[[2]]]]

If[a[[1]] > 0, DynamicModule[{}, Dynamic[a[[2]]]]]

DynamicModule[{}, If[a[[1]] > 0, Dynamic[a[[2]]]]]

DynamicModule[{}, Dynamic[Refresh[a[[2]], TrackedSymbols -> {a}]]]
```

Comment: The way to avoid this is 1) to use DynamicModule so that you localise your variables to the notebook -- in your example the variable is global so requires kernel evaluation; 2) test the variable in some way and only display if True.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch  Thank you for your suggestions.  I was remiss in failing to point out that I had already tried both without success.

Comment: @Kuba  I understand that `Dynamic` is behaving normally, but this is not what I am seeking.  If it is possible, I would like to start the new session with `Dynamic Updating Enabled` not checked in the `Evaluation` menu, but I do not know how.  Then, I could call `FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["ToggleDynamicUpdating"]]` as the first line of the notebook to reenable dynamic updating, when I first execute the notebook, after which I would have to disable that call, so that dynamic updating would not be unenabled, if I executed the notebook the second time in the same session.  Cumbersome, though.

Comment: `Dynamic[If[ValueQ[a], a[[2]], {}]]` gives `{}` instead of error, is that good enough?

Comment: @bbgodfrey You could delete the output cell of `Dynamic` before saving the notebook. But I guess that's not very convenient. Still looking for an option... Very interesting question =)

Comment: @PavloFesenko  Deleting or commenting out the code block in question, then writing it back or uncommenting it when the code is run in a new session would appear to work, but it is, as you say, not vey convenient.  Thanks for taking the time to look at this question.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Found how to program it! Check this [procedure](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2183/saving-a-notebook-without-output-lines).

Comment: @egwenesedai  Write up your comment as an answer, and I shall upvote it.  I shall not, however, accept it now, because I am hoping for an answer that does not erase the output from the previous session.

Comment: How about `DynamicModule[{}, Dynamic@a[[2]], SaveDefinitions -> True]`

Comment: @SimonWoods Your version is the best. Please post it as an answer.

Comment: @SimonWoods  I agree that your answer is the best.  I was aware of this option but mistakenly assumed that it would not work for my actual code, because the code generates and processes large arrays (which takes a few minutes) before applying `Dynamic`.  In fact, `DynamicModule` appears to save the large arrays in final form rather than recalculating anything.  The price is only a 10% increase in file size, from 2.1 to 2.3 MB.  Please do post your comment as an answer to make it more visible to readers who may wish to do the same thing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`SaveDefinitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SaveDefinitions.html) option of `DynamicModule` for this:

```
DynamicModule[{}, Dynamic@a[[2]], SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Comment: Your solution meets the needs of my actual calculation.  Thanks.  Interestingly, in the simple problem in the question, your `DynamicModule` line of code above gives `a` values that can be used outside the `DynamicModule`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey keep in mind that each module will store `a` and all subsequent definitions separately so if you are not careful the size of the notebook may increase a lot. With simple cases this is very nice solution.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, `SaveDefinitions` adds the definition `a = {1, 2}` to the `Initialization` option of the `DynamicModule` (add `//ToBoxes` to the end of my code to see this). This code gets run when the dynamic stuff is first displayed, so it is just as if you evaluated `a = {1, 2}` in the normal way.

Answer (score 3):

To start your notebook with `Dynamic Updating Enabled` not being checked add this code to your notebook:

```
Dynamic[, Initialization :> FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["ToggleDynamicUpdating"]]]
```

To return the dynamic updating back, you should use `ToggleDynamicUpdating` again, as you correctly mentioned in the comments:

```
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["ToggleDynamicUpdating"]]
a = {1, 2};
Dynamic[a[[2]]]
```

Alternatively, you could program not to save output cells when you close your notebook according to this [procedure](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2183/saving-a-notebook-without-output-lines). No output - no issues with dynamic update =)

Comment: Works, but I would prefer not to lose the output, if possible.  Thanks.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I hope the final version of my answer is closer to what you were looking for, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed, it is (+1).  I agree with your assessment,  however, that the answer by Simon Woods best meets my desired outcome.

Answer (score 3):

Just returning to this question now and after reading your addendum I don't think you have adequately set up your test. For example here we see that when the kernel stops the value of `a` is not preserved and you get error boxes appearing:

[image]

If you want `a` to be Global then try this:

```
Dynamic@If[ListQ[a] &&Length[a]>1&& TrueQ[a[[1]] > 0], Dynamic[a[[2]]], Spacer[0]]
```

[image]

It is best to localise your dynamic variables rather than have them global. In order to localise the variable and have its value stored within the notebook you need to make it a `DynamicModule` variable ...which you haven't done in any of your examples. If it is a DM variable then it will "survive" the kernel session.

[image]

Comment: I agree that `DynamicModule` is to be preferred, and I use it in my actual code.  It is not practical, however, to put the equivalent of the `a` definition in it, because doing so would encompass the entire code.